# Convert system time stamp to milliseconds

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

In Informatica Cloud i am trying to convert current system datetime to milliseconds.

This is not working as expected

```
TO_CHAR( Systimestamp() ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Below link might be helpful for you in understanding more about conversion of timestamps.

[Convert string datetime to Informatica datetime](https://network.informatica.com/thread/44892)